# Выделение обращений

Tags: запятые

Простите (1) верные (2) дубравы!

Прости (3) беспечный мир (4) полей (5)

И легкокрылые забавы (6)

Столь быстро улетевших дней!

Прости (7) Тригорское (8) где радость

Меня встречала столько раз!

На то ль узнал я вашу сладость,

Чтоб навсегда покинуть вас?

От вас беру воспоминанье,

А сердце оставляю вам.

Быть может (сладкое мечтанье!)(9)

Я к вашим возвращусь полям…

Решая один из вариантов ЕГЭ, я столкнулась с подобным заданием, ответом к которому являются цифры 135789.
Объясните, пожалуйста, насколько обоснована постановка запятой на месте №5, потому что, по идее, союз соединяет однородные обращения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотите, чтоб было "прости, мир полей и забавы"? Так будет совсем плохо. Хотя и у Пушкина фраза не стопроцентно корректна, по моему скромному мнению. Но ведь это не чувствуется, если не браться за анализ.

А это точно было в ЕГЭ? Странно.

Comment: По-хорошему, надо бы глагол поставить в множественное число, но даже и с этим не очень понятно, что имеется в виду под данной фразой, ведь, убирая обращение, смысл полностью рассыпается.

Comment: А может быть, мне, как восьмикласснику, не понять подобных тонкостей, которые кажутся несуразными.

Comment: Екатерина Молодцова:
Почему на цифре 5 стоит запятая? Союз и связывает однородные обращения и не должен обособляться

Татьяна Стаценко
Случай непростой, действительно.

У Пушкина:

Прости (ед. ч.), бес­печ­ный мир полей, (только мир полей - прости), если бы были однородные обращения, то было бы - простите, поэтому и отделяются эти обращения. И ещё: обращения не могут быть однородными, потому что об однородности можно говорить только в случае, если речь идёт о членах предложения, обращения - это грамматически не связанные с остальными членами слова, они не являются членами предложения.

Comment: Объяснение не убеждает. Насчет однородности: *Саша, Маша и Даша, идите сюда!* – что это, как не однородные обращения? Но вы сами должны были его (это объяснение) найти. Наверняка в сети имеются и другие объяснения. На мой взгляд, включать это в ЕГЭ нельзя, поскольку исходная фраза некорректна (прости, Пушкин!)

Comment: Насколько я поняла, всё, что Вы отправили, – это объяснение, найденное в интернете?

Comment: Да, в первом комменте.